# Can't exec ifconfig with php

Tags: php, apache, exec, ifconfig

I can't execute ifconfig with exec() in PHP on apache. I can execute all kind of commands including ip addr list but that one sucks balls so I would really need to be able to execute ifconfig.

I've read other posts and have made sure that the disable_functions is = "" [blank], but still no luck (I restarted apache ). It feels like it some kind of permission problem since all other commands works just fine.

In the first file i just do exec and then cleans up the result as I want it, and I'm quite sure that isn't where the problem is, since it works fine fore other commands

First file

```
function execute($command){
  exec($command, $output);

  $output_array;                                    // each row contains a array representing all elements in a output row
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($output); $i++){
    $tmp_array = explode(" ",$output[$i]);      
    $output_array[$i] = $tmp_array;
}
// clear the array from all ""
  $clean_array;                             
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($output_array); $i++){
    $tmp;
    $index = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($output_array[$i]); $j++){
        if (strlen($output_array[$i][$j]) > 0){
            $tmp[$index++] = $output_array[$i][$j];
        }
    }
    $clean_array[$i] = $tmp;
  }
  return $clean_array;
```

second file

```
include "../app_includes/application_functions.php";
$command = "ifconfig";
//$command = "ip addr list";
$arr = execute($command);
// print the result
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($arr[$i]); $j++){
        echo $arr[$i][$j]." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

SOLVED:
 The problem was solved by executing "/sbin/ifconfig" instead of only ifconfig

Comment: I'm not sure you can call ifconfig in exec if you not specified it in your php.ini

Comment: how would I add it there, i.e. what should I write?

Comment: have you tried to do in your command line: su -u www-data -c /sbin/ifconfig? What's the result?

Comment: @gafreax Never do that! It might create a security flaw! You don't need to do this

Comment: @ThibaultM why is a security flaw? I don't say to do this that in php script! Anyway two things:  first it's exactly like php that execute the command, second if you can do "su" or "sudo" via exec call on php it's a big security flaw! But's different from what I say.

Comment: @gafreax my apologies, i thought you change /sbin/ifconfig rights... I read to fast...

Comment: @ThibaultM no problem, I'm always interested in Security issue, and I'm curious about what I doesn't know!

Comment: @gafreax I agree! This is the best way to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal user can't use ifconfig on some Gnu/Linux but can use /sbin/ifconfig. So try this

```
<?php
$command="/sbin/ifconfig";
exec($command, $output);
?>
```

To be sure about the path, tape this in your terminal

```
whereis ifconfig
```